# Retrieval of information from a workbook using unique ID

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks , one is a active list(database) and the other is a project tracker(dashboard).

Both workbooks have a project ID.

I want that the workbook and active list should have a loop to match the exact project IDs.

If the project ID is found in the active list, it would retrieve information from that row and overwrite the existing row in the project tracker,which contains that project ID.

This is an example of the code which i have done, I did something relevant but it does not seem to work :

```
Sub AAA()

'If Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value Then
'Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
Dim a As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet

    Set target = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set source = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = source.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = target.Cells(2, target.Columns.Count).Column

    target.Activate

For a = 2 To 50

     If source.Range("A" & a).Value = target.Range("A" & a).Value Then

     target.Range("C" & a).Select
     Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0)).Copy
     source.Range("B" & a).PasteSpecial

     End If

Next a



End Sub
```

Comment: This could be achieved using a Vlookup/Index-Match?

Comment: vlookup can be very tedious for over 6000 rows of data and the database expands every month. A change of location could ruin the whole document thus i do not want to take such a risk @99moorem

Comment: Should Dim and Set the workbooks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how you use the `Range` object. This `.Range("A").Value` does not work, you need to include a row number as well, such as `.Range("A1").Value`.

Your logic assumes that both lists are in exactly the same order. Using the `Range.Find` method gets round that problem.

```
Sub AAA()
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellFound As Range

    Set target = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set source = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each cell In target.Range("A2:A50")
        ' Try to find this value in the source sheet
        Set cellFound = source.Range("A:A").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
            ' A matching value was found
            ' So copy the cell 2 columns across to the cell adjacent to matching value
            ' Do a "normal" copy & paste
            cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Copy cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
            ' Or do a copy & paste special values
            'cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Copy
            'cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Else
            ' The value in this cell does not exist in the source
            ' Should anything be done?
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Are you aware that you are using different sheets for `source` and for `target`?

Comment: hi there, the code works but it only works if the cells on both workbooks of different sheet correspond on the same rows.  if the data is in row 1 of target but row 3 in source it does not find and match it @ChipsLetten

Comment: I've just checked and it works fine. The `Range.Find` method means that the order of the items isn't important. Can you give an example of it not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
target.Activate

For a = 2 To 50

 If source.Range("A" & a).Value = target.Range("A" & a).Value Then

 target.Range("C" & a).EntireRow.Select
 Selection.Copy
 source.Range("B" & a).PasteSpecial

 End If
```

Next a

Comment: -what is `target.Range("A")`? that is not a valid range is it?

Comment: You can use cells instead of range to compare the two data.  source.Cells(a, 1).Value = target.Cells(a, 1).Value

Yes. It should be target.Range("A" & a). Sorry about that.

Comment: it defines rows! @John F

Comment: try using      target.Range("A" & a)

Comment: i tried, the programme runs but nothing comes out. @John F

Comment: Try target.Range("C" & a).Entirerow.select. The row of the activecell will be selected and copied to another workook.

Comment: it only works if the rows are exactly in the same order if it is not then it does not display. i think we have to incorporate a find coding in it but im not sure on how do i go about it @JohnF

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what volume of data you're going to be working with, but you could also use [arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) to achieve what you're after.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AAA()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer
    Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet
    Dim arrTarget() As Variant, arrSource() As Variant
    Dim lrowSrc As Long, lcolSrc As Long, lrowTrgt As Long, lcolTrgt As Long

    Set target = Workbooks("Book4.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set source = Workbooks("Book3.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1")
    lrowSrc = source.Cells(target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcolSrc = source.Cells(2, source.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrowTrgt = target.Cells(target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcolTrgt = target.Cells(2, target.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    target.Activate
    arrTarget = target.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lrowTrgt, lcolSrc))
    source.Activate
    arrSource = source.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lrowSrc, lcolSrc))
    target.Activate

    For i = LBound(arrTarget, 1) To UBound(arrTarget, 1)
        For j = LBound(arrSource, 1) To UBound(arrSource, 1)
            If arrTarget(i, 1) = arrSource(j, 1) Then
                For k = LBound(arrSource, 2) To UBound(arrSource, 2)
                    arrTarget(i, k) = arrSource(j, k)
                Next k
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    target.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrTarget, 1), UBound(arrTarget, 2)).Value = arrTarget
End Sub
```

> Working on 12,000 rows of data in the `Target workbook` and 25,000 in the `Source workbook`, with 6,000 matches, the code took 9.91 seconds to run.